# When is it valid to take only the positive square root of a number when doing proofs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

So there is this question of proving where the minimum value occurs of this expression:

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ where $x > 0$

After using the A.G.M. inequality:

$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$

$2\sqrt{xy} \leq x+y$

where $a = x^2$ and $b = \frac{25}{x^2}$, one gets:

$2\sqrt{25} \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$

$10 \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$

Now, apparently $\sqrt{25}$ can just simply only take the positive square root. But why don't we consider the negative?

Comment: You can certainly take the negative square root to obtain the looser bound $-10 \leq x^2 + 25/x^2$, but that's not particularly useful considering that the tighter bound $0 \leq x^2 + 25/x^2$ holds trivially.

Comment: Generally when we write $\sqrt{x}$, we mean the unique non-negative real number $y$ such that $y^2 =x$. In other words, we take the 'non-negative square root'.

Comment: @Bungo Hi, what do you mean by "loser bound"? The expression never actually goes to $-10$.

Comment: @Hayden Yes, I understand that, but why is it simply ignored?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. If you took the negative square root of $25$, the LHS in your final inequality would have been $-10$. The inequality $-10 \leq x^2 + 25/x^2$ is certainly true, but it provides no information since we can see that the right hand side is nonnegative.

Comment: @Bungo Okay thanks. So if I were proving this, would I consider the two cases? How would the negative square root affect it?

Comment: @Strikers I guess what I'm saying is that in the statement of the AM-GM inequality, the meaning of $\sqrt{xy}$ is meant to be the non-negative square root. There isn't really any loss of generality since $-\sqrt{xy} \leq \sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$.

Comment: @Bungo Okay, thank you. May one of you answer it so I can check it as a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Hayden Wait because the left side of the A.G.M. inequality cannot be negative, would it be even valid to consider the negative square root?

Comment: Of course you can consider it. As @Hayden said, if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, then we always have $-\sqrt{xy} \leq 0 \leq \sqrt{xy} \leq (x+y)/2$. But only the rightmost of that chain of inequalities provides any nontrivial information.

Comment: @Bungo Okay, thank you.

Comment: " So if I were proving this, would I consider the two cases?" Have you seen a proof of the AM/GM theorem?  It takes many forms but it's usually $(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)^2 \ge 0$ so $x- 2\sqrt{x}{y} + y \ge 0$ so $x + y \ge 2\sqrt{x}{y}$.  The negative square roots have nothing to do with anything.  In proving the theorem we aren't actually *solving* anything and we are not actually "taking" any square roots.  We are being "given" square roots.  That's the exact opposite. (if you think of it that way).

Comment: @fleablood So are you saying Bungo is wrong in his explanation that you can take the negative root?

Comment: Uh.....no. Of course you can take the negative root.  You can take the natural log and you can multiply it by 27 and put whipped cream on it for all I care.  The point is the theorem tells you something about the positive square root which is useful rather than anything about the negative square root which is trivial and useless.

Comment: @fleablood Okay that makes sense, and it seems correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

We don't take the negative square root for the same reason we don't take the number $17$ or  $\pi^3$ or why we don't take the natural log of the number.

Because that is not what the theorem tells us.

The AM-GM theorem says that $\sqrt{xy} \le \frac{x + y}2$ and that is a theorem about the positive square root.

It is not a theorem about the negative square root.  It is not a theorem about the number $17$ or $\pi^3$ or about the natural log.

It is not a theorem about saying "there is a number $u$ so that $u^2 = xy$ and we can conclude $u \le \frac {x + y}2$ but we will have to solve for $u$".  It is a theorem that the value $\sqrt{xy}$, which happens to be non  -negative, which the theorem *gives* us on a silver platter and which we are *NOT* being asked to solve for, that non-negative number $\sqrt{xy}$, is such that $\sqrt{xy} \le \frac {x+y}2$.

Okay, so why *don't* we have a theorem about the negative square root?  Why don't we have a theorem that $\pm\sqrt{xy}\le\frac{x+y}2$?  After all that is probably certainly true one would think.

Well, it *is* true but because $x \ge 0; y \ge 0$ (a necessary condition to the theorem) then we have $-\sqrt{xy} \le 0\le \frac {x+y}2$ and $-\sqrt{xy}\le \frac {x+y}2$ is trivial and not needed.  And $\pm \sqrt{xy}\le \frac {x+y} 2$ is a weaker theorem.

If we used that as a theorem, call it $A.M/G.M/B.S$ then we'd get

Okay $x^2 > 0$ and $\frac 25{x^2}> 0$ so by the $A.M/G.M/B.S$ we have $\pm 2\sqrt{x^2*\frac 25{x^2}} = \pm 10 < x^2 + \frac {25}{x^2}$.

But why should we use the $A.M/G.M/B.S$ theorem when we can use the *stronger* A.M/G.M theorem that says $2\sqrt{25}=10 \le x^2 + \frac {25}{x^2}$.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/power-mean-qagh/ Obviously not true if you allow negative numbers.  Take $-1,-1,2$.  Then $AM$ is $0$ and $GM =\sqrt[3] 2$.  But that's not the point.  The point is we are *solving* anything by taking roots.  The theorem is *giving* us the roots.

Comment: Okay this makes sense, the theorem actually is only for the positive root as the negative root is trivial. (It is just that they don't put a "$+$" sign to indicate "_only considered for positive roots_". Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \left( x - \frac{5}{x} \right)^2  \geq 0  $$
$$ x^2 - 10 + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 0 $$
$$ x^2  + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 10 $$

seems to me I did the same thing a few days ago

Answer (score 0):

The use of not using the negative answer to the equation is because of its relevancy to the actual equation (and answer). Taking the negative root *is valid*, however *irrelevant* because you:

"*obtain the looser bound $−10 \leq x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2}$, but that's not particularly useful considering that the tighter bound $10≤x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$ holds trivially.*" It *holds trivially* because knowing that that an expression such as $x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2}$ is always going to be more than or equal to $0$ (because its being added and squared), then knowing that it is more than a certain positive number is where the minimum can actually be at.

(from comments in original post @Bungo).

Also, note, it is valid to take the negative square root, even though the AGM inequality states that $xy$ have to be more than $0$ because you would just put the negative outside of the square root.